# "Any term" chracter (_) in DCG not working as expected

Tags: prolog, dcg

I'm looping through a list of sentences and trying to verify if they're grammatically correct. The sentences are lists of words. That looks like this:

```
verifySen([]).
verifySen([H|T]) :-
  sentence(H,[]),
  verifySen(T).
```

Where verifySen is fed a list of lists. The `sentence(H,[])` tries to check if something is a valid sentence. This is where the problem is. My current DCG looks like this:

```
    sentence --> subject_phrase, verb_phrase, {write('this IS a valid sentence'), nl}.
    sentence --> anything, {write('this is NOT a valid sentence'),nl}.
    anything --> [_], anything.
    ...
```

The code **works** for when something **is** a valid sentence, but fails and produces an error when something is an invalid sentence. I get `stream '<stream>(000..random numbers...)' does not exist.`

Can anyone provide advice?

Comment: Assume that `[you,run]` is a valid sentence. Then according to you `[you,run,xxxx]` is not a valid sentence, but still you will write out that it is one! This does not happen if you write these tests one level above. And always use `phrase(sentence,H)` as the interface to a grammar.

Comment: If I change it to

 `sentence --> subject_phrase, verb_phrase, {write('this IS a sentence'), nl}.
 sentence --> [_],!, {write('this is NOT a sentence'),nl}.`

Would that solve the problem? Trace also shows that it correctly detects that something isn't a sentence, but then goes and tests it again but without the first word. Does this have to do with using [_] or not using a cut?

Comment: Do not put any `{}` into the grammar rules!

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. This doesn't fix the issue though

Comment: What query did you enter when you saw that error? Also, if you have only one clause for `anything --> [_], anything.` then you're saying anything is an infinite sequence. What code lives at ... and beyond?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the base case of anything//0, so when the sentence is invalid it will run 'til the end-of-stream and then fail. Should be

```
 anything --> [_], anything.
 anything --> [].
```